# Help understand energy part of Moon

Tags: moon

IMDb's summary of Moon (2009) is as follow:

> Astronaut Sam Bell has a quintessentially personal encounter toward
> the end of his three-year stint on the Moon, where he, working
> alongside his computer, GERTY, sends back to Earth parcels of a
> resource that has helped diminish our planet's power problems.

I largely understood the movie. But after watching movie, when I read the summary again, I couldn't relate last line. It says like it sends back to Earth parcels of a resource to fix energy problems. What was that parcel? I couldn't see it in movie. Was that sent in a space vehicle? I noticed a space vehicle leaving the base in the beginning of movie, when Sam types something on computer and vehicle takes off, as shown in picture below:

[image]

Does it contain the energy needed on earth?

Further, I noticed many Combine Harvesters like things. What was the purpose of them? Were *they* creating energy and sending back to earth in the vehicle?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_(2009_film)

Answer (score 7):

The automated Harvester vehicles are collecting [Helium-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium-3) a material that is a hypothetical future energy source and can possibly be [mined from the moon's surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium-3#Extraterrestrial_mining)

The base that Sam is based on has a [Mass Driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_driver) for launching collected Helium 3 - presumably to some Earth orbit to be collected.

You say "what was that parcel" .. but we do see the younger Sam get into one of the vehicle's that normally just contains Helium 3, that is launched to Earth towards the end of the movie.

This is all explained in quite some detail in the [wikipedia page for the movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_(2009_film)).